# How to run pyflyte serialize workflows

Tags: flyte

I am trying to learn flyte and how pyflyte serializes workflow to pb.

I used `pyflyte  init test` to create an example test, then i tried to run `pyflyte --verbose serialize workflows` inside that `test` folder: and I always got:

```
Loading packages [] under source root /Users/<my-username>/repos/flyte-example/test
Successfully serialized 0 flyte objects
```

I also read it https://docs.flyte.org/projects/flytekit/en/latest/pyflyte.html#pyflyte-serialize but could not figure it out.

I want to share the `pyflyte` version, but there isn't flag to show version:

```
❯ pyflyte  --help

Usage: pyflyte [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Entrypoint for all the user commands.

Options:
  --verbose          Show verbose messages and exception traces
  -k, --pkgs TEXT    Dot-delineated python packages to operate on. Multiple
                     may be specified (can use commas, or specify the switch
                     multiple times. Please note that this option will
                     override the option specified in the configuration file,
                     or environment variable

  -c, --config TEXT  Path to config file for use within container
  --help             Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  backfill     The backfill command generates and registers a new workflow...
  init         Create flyte-ready projects.
  local-cache  Interact with the local cache.
  package      This command produces a Flyte backend registrable package of...
  register     This command is similar to ``package`` but instead of...
  run          This command can execute either a workflow or a task from
               the...

  serialize    This command produces protobufs for tasks and templates.
```

```
❯ pip list | grep flytekit
flytekit                          1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You needn't use `pyflyte serialize` if you use `pyflyte run` or `pyflyte register` command. I highly recommend you to try out our [getting started guide](https://docs.flyte.org/projects/cookbook/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: thanks for the response. i am trying to learn more details under the hook.